# Can not use Gallry in Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, gallery

Im using eclipse for android development. I need to add image gallery to project.
When I import

import android.widget.Gallery;

it display like this

[image]

Why this happen?

Comment: You can go for `GridView` which will also fullfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check the official documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Gallery has been deprecated in API level 16. Which means it will no longer be a supported component and there will be no active development.

Comment: So what should I do. What to use instead of Gallery? Please help

Comment: Really depends on what you are trying to achieve. The other components mentioned in the documentation can be used - HorizontalScrollView, ViewPager. Some apps use GridView also.

Comment: I'm trying to browse image and set to gallery. I need create  list of images.

Comment: GridView seems most appropriate in that situation. You can find a host of tutorials of image browser with GridView. Just search for it on the internet/ stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

As the stated in the [Gallery Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) its deprecated and no apps can be uploaded on market which contains the `Gallery`.

So you can use the `GridView` by creating a custom layout for it and show the images into it which will fulfill your requirement of showing images.

Check out the [Simple tutorial of GridView](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/display-images-in-gridview.html)

[GridView with Image](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/748050-how-to-set-up-a-list-of-clickable-images-in-android-app-development-with-gridview)